# how to properly set cookies with python requests

Tags: python, cookies, beautifulsoup, python-requests

my code is as follow:

```
r = requests.session()
response = r.get(url=url_to_start)
price_table=[]
while len(price_table) < 100:
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, features='html.parser')
        souplist = soup.find_all(attrs={"class": "col-xs-3"})
        souptxt=''
        for i in souplist:
            souptxt+=str(i)
        list1=re.findall(patterne,souptxt)
        price_table.extend(list1)
        response = r.get(url=url_to_follow)
```

However, the script crashes with an antirobot plugin. I would like to configure request so as it uses my navigator session cookie and headers. How do I find the header and cookie sent by my navigator and configure it in request please?

Comment: the cookies will set them selves, they will persist in the object you call `r`

Comment: you can print the cookies by `response.cookies` or `r.cookies`

Comment: but i would like to use my navigator cookie

Comment: You can add import and export cookies as json. So if you have some JSON encoded cookies then you can import them

Comment: how do i see the cookies associated with my navigator and with a specific website?

Comment: I dont know you havn't specified what your navigator cookie is :')